# How to add a JetBrains IDE to the Plank if "Keep in Dock" does not appear

Tags: plank, desktop

I use several of JetBrains IDEs for software development (IntelliJ, CLion, PyCharm). After updating PyCharm one time, its Plank icon disappeared. Running the .sh file in the PyCharm/bin directory opened the program, but the right-clicking the icon did not produce the "Keep in Dock" option as normal. I fumbled around on the internet, but couldn't find any information for a fix. I tried using the answer provided [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/560/how-can-i-add-an-executable-file-to-the-dock), but it didn't seem to do anything.

How do I keep the shortcuts to my IDEs on the Plank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After installing another IDE from the JetBrains suite, I saw the installer mention that I could add the program to my Applications drawer by going to Tools > Create Desktop Entry...

As far as I can tell, this creates a .desktop entry with all the right information included. Doing that made it so I could then open the program, right-click on the icon in the Plank, and select "Keep in Dock".

[A similar solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220512/how-can-i-create-launcher-icon-for-phpstorm) from AskUbuntu.

Comment: Jetbrains makes it easy that way. If you were to run into this issue with another application, the solution is to create a .desktop file and save it to ~/.local/share/applications. Would you mind marking your question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, JetBrains created the new `.desktop` file, but my OS was still using the old one. A simple move fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same problem. And I guess you didn't check **'Create the entry for all users (requires superuser privileges)'** on Tools -> Create Desktop Entry.
You should check this one.